# How do I use protobuf files?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use an API that distributes public transit information. They distribute this information through the GTFS Real-time format (https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/reference). What the API actually provides to me is simply a vehiclepositions.pb file. I've read through the protobuf documentation (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), yet I can't seem to understand how to interact with this file.

For all of the compatible languages, protobufs seem to convert from a .proto to a .pb.h, .java, .py, etc. They create a source code that can be imported into files and referenced. How do I take this generic .pb file and turn it into one of these source code files?

I've been reading through documentation and looking this problem up everywhere but can't seem to resolve it. I'd appreciate any help you guys can give.

Comment: Can you show us what this `.pb` file looks like? Is it human readable?

Comment: https://gtfs-rt.itsmarta.com/TMGTFSRealTimeWebService/vehicle/vehiclepositions.pb Here's a direct link to the file. It is not human readable.

Comment: You put tags on this question for too many languages (.NET, Java, C, and Go). What programming language are you actually planning to use for this project?

Comment: I'm planning on C++, however I would imagine the solution to this problem is very similar regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded file named `vehiclepositions.pb` that you mention contains only the data, not the Protocol Buffer definitions.

In order to read the data, you need to start with the `.proto` file that describes the data format and use [`protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/) (or [`buf`](https://docs.buf.build/introduction)) to generate the files that are needed for your language.

**Google provides the `gtfs-realtime.proto` file [here](https://developers.google.com/static/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime.proto).**

Since you mentioned in the comments that you plan to use C++, you will need to download the `.proto` file, the `protoc` compiler, and the C++ protobuf runtime, and build C++ bindings for it using a command like this (the exact command that works for you might be slightly different):

```
protoc --cpp_out=$DEST_DIR gtfs-realtime.proto
```

This will generate `gtfs-realtime.pb.h` and `gtfs-realtime.pb.cc` which you can use in your project.

With the `.proto` file linked above, you should be able to follow the C++ protobuf tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) substituting this `.proto` file in place of the sample file in the tutorial.